# White text on gray background in "n/5 Commited" is very hard to read

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

I started to look into documentation today, and found that there was no tag for SPARQL yet, so I went to propose one.  In the "progress bar" showing how many users have committed, there's text "n/5 Committed" that is almost invisible before anyone has committed.  Maybe this could be made a bit more readable?

#### Before committing

[image: white on gray background]

#### After committing

[image: white on green]

Comment: I'm never sure whether "this is really hard to read" is a bug report or a feature request ("please make this easier to read"), so feel free to retag.  This obviously isn't a high-priority item, but I was slowed down when I noticed "there's something there" and spent a moment trying to read it.

Comment: When it's *that* hard to read, I'd call it a bug.